# How to filter entities in form selects based on ACLs

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a simple app that manages product and category entities. The CRUD for these is managed with SonataAdmin.

My `Product` entity is associated with the `Category` entity (many-to-one association). What I want is that when Sonata's CRUD shows the form to create Products, in the category select, it lists only the categories on which the user has an `EDIT` Access Control Entry.

Here is some code to illustrate this:

`Product` entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @var integer id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /*Getters and setters
    ...
    */
}
```

`Category` entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /*Getters and setters
    ...
    */
}
```

The `ProductAdmin` for Sonata CRUD

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class ProductAdmin extends Admin
{

    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Product name'))

            // HOWTO FILTER THESE ???
            ->add('category', 'entity', array('class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category'))

            ->add('price')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    /* More here, but kept short for the example
    ...
    */

}
```

What I'd like is a way to check for ACL in the `ProductAdmin::configureFormFields` whithin the call to `->add('category', 'entity', array('class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Category'))`

Any help much appreciated.
FL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to filter your entity list with the `query_builder` option of your field ([doc is here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)) but I'm not sure about how to create a query builder filtering on ACL.

Another (better?) solution I see is :

1. declare your form as a service ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services))
2. inject the security context as a dependance and any other dependance you need
3. request the list of `Category` you want in your form using injected services
4. set your form categories with the `choices` option of entity field, give its your `Category` list as an array ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choices))

Should works...

Comment: The solution with dependency injection seems to be the good one, but I have one last problem (before accepting the answer). In the case of edition forms I need to be able to disable some fields based on ACL of the edited object. (like allowing change of a product's category only if user as the 'EDIT' right on the category). This would require access to the edited object within the Admin::getForm call which doesn't seem to be the case in sonata's Admin classes. Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, I found he proper solution for my needs: It's called FormEventSubscriber : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer just to make [F.L. comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024368/how-to-filter-entities-in-form-selects-based-on-acls#comment-33407377) in [maphe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024368/how-to-filter-entities-in-form-selects-based-on-acls#answer-21033276) standing up, as it was the solution for his own question and a great help for me.

The Symfony cookbook has the answer documented:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

The document describes how to solve many common problems where dynamic forms are needed. I cite the intro of the document here:

> Often times, a form can't be created statically. In this entry, you'll
>   learn how to customize your form based on three common use-cases:
>
> 1. Customizing your Form Based on the Underlying Data
>
>    Example: you have a "Product" form and need to modify/add/remove a
>      field based on the data on the underlying Product being edited.
> 2. How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data
>
>    Example: you create a "Friend Message" form and need to build a
>      drop-down that contains only users that are friends with the current
>      authenticated user.
> 3. Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms
>
>    Example: on a registration form, you have a "country" field and a
>      "state" field which should populate dynamically based on the value in
>      the "country" field.